# Replicating a schema or tables from a Linux Postgres to a Windows Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

We have a database running on an Azure Linux machine (version 9.6 of Postgres).

Locally, we have a workstation which is running Windows 10 and Postgres 9.65. This workstation has a lot more memory and storage, and I would like to use it as another backup, and to allow users to query from it without worry about any impacts to my production server.

Is it possible to do a cross-OS replication in a non-complicated manner?

If not, can I/should I install Postgres using the Ubuntu for Windows 10 feature, so it looks like the same operating system?

Or should I just implement some Foreign Data Wrappers, and then create materialized views that they can query? Thanks!